# Should I share an AWS application load balancer between applications?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-alb

I have two unrelated applications ( they are not two microservices of the same application, but two separate services ) running on Amazon Ec2 or Fargate. Should I share an application loadbalancer using path-based routing or have a separate loadbalancer for each application? What's the best practice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some deeper research, it seems that sharing Application load balancers can be an effective way to reduce costs, with no downside.

A more appropriate solution than path-based routing when having different applications using the same ALB is host-based routing. Host-based routing is transparent for the underlying applications as it doesn't require them to know about the path the Listener Rule uses to dispatch the requests of their clients.

Useful references:

- [Consolidating AWS Load Balancers using host-based routing](https://medium.com/signiant-engineering/consolidating-aws-load-balancers-using-host-based-routing-212f5949fca7)
- [Host-based routing support for Application Load Balancers](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-host-based-routing-support-for-aws-application-load-balancers/)

Comment: I agree that this seems like a good approach. Someone with significant practical experience may let you know if this has any practical issues.